# VBA looping search, copy, paste error: need macro to skip cells with blanks or non-numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code I cobbled together from other people on the internet for a macro that:

1. Searches Column A for a user-inputted number.
2. Copies row
3. Pastes on another sheet

... across all sheets in a folder.

The issue is that the code requires the value in column A to be a number greater than 0. However, there are blanks and text in column A.

I need the macro to run over those.

I've experimented with limits but I am too inept to figure anything out without breaking the rest of it.

Here is the code

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)

     Dim LSearchRow As Long        '# Integer creates 16-bit value which requires
     Dim LCopyToRow As Long        '# special processing on post-16-bit computers
     Dim LSearchValue As String

     Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet      '# Faster and more convenient if you are
     Dim WshtDest As Worksheet     '# working with more than one worksheet

     Set WshtSrc = Worksheets("Search")  '# These are probably the wrong
     Set WshtDest = Worksheets("Dest")   '# worksheet names

    LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter the staff ID.", "Enter value")

    'Start search in row 5
    LSearchRow = 1

    'Start copying data to row 5 in Sheet1 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 1
 
    With WshtSrc

    While Len(.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0                 '#

      'If value in column A = LSearchValue, copy entire row to Sheet1
      If .Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then       '#

      .Rows(LSearchRow).Copy Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1)

        '# 'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        '# Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        '# Selection.Copy

        '# 'Paste row into Sheet1 in next row
        '# Sheets("Search").Select
        '# Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        '# ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        '# 'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        '# Sheets("Search").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

    Wend

    'Position on cell A3
    'Range("A3").Select

    End With

    '# Err_Execute:
    '#    MsgBox "An error occurred."

            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: check out the Val and IsNumeric functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/val-function 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function 
you could add an if statement above your existing inner if statement to test the value of the cell and only execute the inner if block, if the value is a number (IsNumeric = True) and is greater than 0 (Val > 0), see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
If Val(.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) Then
    If .Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then
        .Rows(LSearchRow).Copy Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1)
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
    End If
End If
```

also, you can drop Cstr in these, `.Range("A" & LSearchRow).Value` works just as well